# How could I do the sum of all values of a nested hash?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, sum

I have a nested hash like this

```
Aranea={
  "Aranéomorphes"=>{
    "Agelenidae"=>[80,1327],
"Amaurobiidae"=>[49,270],
"Ammoxenidae"=>[4,18],
"Anapidae"=>[58,233],
"Anyphaenidae"=>[56,572],
"Araneidae"=>[175,3074],
"Archaeidae"=>[5,90],
"Arkydiae"=>[2,38],
"Austrochilidae"=>[3,10],
"Caponiidae"=>[18,119],
"Cheiracanthiidae"=>[12,353],
"Cithaeronidae"=>[2,8],
"Clubionidae"=>[16,639],
"Corinnidae"=>[68,489],
"Ctenidae"=>[48,519],......
```

For each key (spiders families), the array represents [number of genders, number of species].

Iwould like to get the sum of all first elements....i.e all the genders in total....

I tried different things without success like :

```
genre = []

#total = genre.transpose.map {|x| x.reduce(:+)}
```

Or....

```
def sum_deeply(h)
  h.values.inject(0) { |m, v| 
    m + (Hash === v[0] ? sum_deeply(v[0]) : v[0].to_i) 
  } 
end
puts sum_deeply(Aranea)
```

But none does work for with transpose I get a no implicit conversion error...

Could anyone enligthen me on this ? Thanks

!!! Update.... 08.07.2020... solution found with

```
families = Aranea
num_genders = families.flat_map do |_family_name, species_hash|
  num_genders, _num_species = species_hash.values.transpose
  num_genders
```

Thanks to Kache for his help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
families = Aranea
num_genders = families.flat_map do |_family_name, species_hash|
  num_genders, _num_species = species_hash.values.transpose
  num_genders
end
num_genders.inject(:+)
```

Just a tip: splitting out the "data extraction" and "data processing" (i.e. accessing the `num_genders` value vs summing them) will make your code easier to follow.

I don't think there'll be any part of the above that you won't understand, but if there is, just let me know what parts you'd like to have explained.

Comment: Thanks... Just a question my hash is Aranea={Araneomorphes=>{"Agelenidae"=>[80,1327],
"Amaurobiidae"=>[49,270],
"Ammoxenidae"=>[4,18], etc .. etc... Shall I replace in your code families by Aranea or Aranea[Araneomorphes] ? I don't really get it actually. Thanx

Comment: Your `Aranea` hash is a `Hash` of spider families, hence the name, `families`. New variables can be created to refer to the same data, e.g. `families = Aranea`.

Comment: I also renamed some variables to be more explicit, and I'm now using `transpose` instead of `map(&:first)` since you expressed intent to use that method in your question. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot . I do get the total of genders . I got this right. But if I do want the total of species... Shall I do this : families = Aranea
num_genders = families.flat_map do |_family_name, species_hash|
  num_genders, _num_species = species_hash.values.transpose
  num_species
end
num_species.inject(:+) ?

Comment: In our examples so far, we extract one set of data (`num_genders`) and discard the other (`_num_species`). If you need both, let's not discard one only to rerun everything again while discarding the other: `num_genders, num_species = families.values.flat_map(&:values).transpose`. Sorry don't have room in a comment to explain, submit another question instead, if you'd like.

Comment: Thanx again it works fine . I do have total of genders and total of species...

Comment: would you upvote and accepted my answer then? I'd appreciate it

Comment: I'd like to but how can I do this ?